# python randomly opening the command prompt reinstall to get back to work

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pycharm

this has been very frustrating now, like once every 2 days my anaconda just stops working correctly , i am using pycharm as my IDE and everything works fine , suddenly i find my anaconda terminal (command prompt if u will) starting randomly for no obvious reason , if i hit run on pycharm it opens the terminal and doesn't do anything , if i navigate to my .py file location and try to run it through command prompt it simply runs a new command prompt ( the python command prompt ) and does nothing no code is running its awaiting further commands. is this normal ? anyone has a solution to this 
i am using windows 7

Comment: to add more info : every time for example i do anything with python it just opens the terminal , for example if i type at the location of my helloworld.py file python hellowrld.py it just opens a terminal if i go inside pycharm and i go to tools->python console it opens 2 consoles and i have to reinstall it to work correctly

Comment: Looks like you have installed Anaconda as the default python and have selected the option to run python files in separate console. Look in anaconda documentation to disable that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this issue by uninstalling everything related to python from my computer and removing all environment variables as well , reinstalling anaconda after that to its default location fixed the problem .